# Maven can't resolve dependency with Central repo

Tags: maven, cas, mvn-repo

I'm trying to build project with following dependency

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-webapp-config-server</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and I see following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building sso 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.926s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Nov 09 18:46:12 SAMT 2018
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sso: Could not resolve dependencies for project mrb:sso:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apereo.cas:cas-server-webapp-config-server:jar:5.3.5 in http://central.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

But! We can see, that both, Central and Sonatype repos, has this dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apereo.cas/cas-server-webapp-config-server/5.3.5

Does anyone have idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Find .m2 folder and delete existing downloaded jars, should work fine.

Comment: try adding `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency is not a jar.

Specify the correct type or classifier.

Comment: Exactly. Thank you!